# Get a constant definition from a specific unit file

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I have a complex Lazarus program. One of my sources `uses` the standard units `Graphics` and `ZStream`, both of them contain a definition for `clDefault`.

The one (in `Graphics`) is:

```
const
    clDefault = TColor($20000000);
```

The other (in `ZStream`) is:

```pascal
type
    Tcompressionlevel=(
      clnone,                     {Do not use compression, just copy data.}
      clfastest,                  {Use fast (but less) compression.}
      cldefault,                  {Use default compression}
      clmax                       {Use maximum compression}
    );
```

In my code when I refer to `clDefault` I get a compiler error, because I want to use the `const` definition above to assign it a destination of `TColor` type, while the compiler tries to use the enumerated constant from `ZStream`.

How can I instruct the compiler to use the correct definition I want?

Comment: In Delphi you can use `Graphics.clDefault` and `TcompressionLevel.clDefault`. I don't know if similar namespaces are implemented in freepascal. Edit, since freepascal 3.0.0 unit namespaces are implemented.

Comment: Thanks; `Graphics.clDefault` would do the trick. If you _do_ have time, an extended answer explaining this in detail will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using unit namespaces you can prefix the `const clDefault` with its unit name:

```
Graphics.clDefault
```

This will let the compiler pinpoint the wanted declaration in this case.

From [Freepascal docs](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu102.html#x241-26500016.6.4):

> The rules of unit scope imply that an identifier of a unit can be redefined. To have access to an identifier of another unit that was redeclared in the current unit, precede it with that other units name...